# What metadata is cached when using cacheResultSetMetadata=true with MySQL JDBC connector?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm playing with different properties listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), in specific with the ones marked as Performance Extensions. I'm testing with **cacheResultSetMetadata**, but can't find documentation on what exactly is cached when the property is set to true.

Also, is there any scenario where using it is recommended/not recommended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First you have to read about [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) that is an object, used to get information about the types and properties of the columns in a `ResultSet` object.

The ResultSet object returned by a SELECT statement also contains column (field) names, lengths and types.

You can use `res.getMetaData()` to retrieve them into a ResultSetMetaData object, which offers the following methods to allow to get different information:

```
getColumnCount()              - Returns the number of columns in this ResultSet object.
getColumnName(int column)     - Get the designated column's name.
getColumnTypeName(int column) - Retrieves the designated column's database-specific type
                                name.
getPrecision(int column)      - Get the designated column's specified column size.
getTableName()                - Returns the qualifier for the underlying table of the
                                ResultSet
getSchemaName()               - Returns the the designated column's table's schema name
getColumnDisplaySize()        - Returns column display length
```

Whether a column is read-only, nullability, automatically numbered, and so on.

Now the property `cacheResultSetMetadata` instruct the driver to cache [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)s and [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s

<sub>You can also specify property `metadataCacheSize` that tells about the number of queries to cache `ResultSetMetadata` for if `cacheResultSetMetaData` is set to 'true' (default 50)</sub>